# How to retrieve string from JSON as Array key-value pair in Jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I'm not able to fetch the value from "statisticalEvidence" in the below JSON output as "key","value" pair.

JSON Output:

```
{
    "query": {
        "count": 1,
        "lang": "en-US",
        "results": {
            "entities": {
                "total": "10",
                "lang": "en-US",
                "entity": [
                    {
                    "id": "FZZNDK3XM3VIPLW76QHCAYF2D4",
                    "rank": "10",
                    "scores": {
                        "score": {
                            "attribute": "contentCreator",
                            "context": "yct:001000012",
                            "value": "1.0",
                            "statisticalEvidence": "\"{\"totalNoOfAbusiveComments\":0,\"totalNoOfThumbsDown\":22,\"totalNoOfPositiveRatedComments\":70,\"totalNoOfReplies\":8,\"totalNoOfLikedComments\":20,\"totalNoOfEngagingReplies\":13,\"totalNoOfThumbsUp\":35,\"totalNoOfComments\":79}\""
                        }
                    }}
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm able to fetch the "id" as below:

```
$.get(url,function(data) {
    var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    for(var i in json.query.results.entities.entity){
    var id = json.query.results.entities.entity[i].id;
        }
});
```

Kindly suggest how to fetch the values in statisticalEvidence as a array.

Comment: You want something like this? `[{key: 'count', value: 1}, {key: 'lang', value: 'en-US'}]`?

Comment: @Brad.. Actually i want to fetch the "totalNoOfAbusiveComments":0,"totalNoOfThumbsDown":22

Comment: That's not an array, that's an object.  Arrays in JavaScript can only have numerical indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below,

```
//should return the string
var se = json.query.results.entities.entity[i].scores.score.statisticalEvidence
```

Then use [`$.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

```
se = $.parseJSON(se);
```

Full code:

```
$.get(url,function(data) {
    var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    for(var i in json.query.results.entities.entity){
       var id = json.query.results.entities.entity[i].id;
       var se = $.parseJSON(json.query.results.entities.entity[i].scores.score.statisticalEvidence);
    }
});
```

**Note:** `statisticalEvidence` in your data is an Object not an Array.

Comment: @vega.. Thanks for your quick response. Actually i did try this and i'm encountering the below error.                             SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data
Source File

Comment: @Ravinandan Try adding these lines.. `se = se.replace(/\\/g, "")` and then `$.parseJSON(se.substring(1, se.length - 1))` should return you an object

Comment: @Vega.. Thanks a lot...$.parseJSON(se.substring(1, se.length - 1)) did the trick...